# Soundcloud resolve issue

Tags: php, api, curl, soundcloud

I am developing an app for SoundCloud, written in PHP and I use the php-soundcloud library.

After successfully having instantiated a Services_Soundcloud instance, I can do calls like the following:

```
echo $soundcloud->get('me');
echo $soudcloud->get('users/12345678');
```

However, the following call is not working:

```
echo $soundcloud->get('resolve', array('url' => 'https://soundcloud.com/webfordreams'));
```

The error I get is:

> Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception: The requested URL responded with HTTP code 302. in Services_Soundcloud->_request() (line 933 of ../php-soundcloud/Services/Soundcloud.php).

After several hours of debugging I decided to ask for help, as I really don't understand what I do wrong.

Can anybody help me and tell me how to get the proper response?

Answer (score 1):

The "HTTP/1.1 302" response that you're getting is the appropriate response according to the [api](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve).
If you inspect the full php exception you'll get this in the response body:

```
[httpBody:protected] => {"status":"302 -Found","location":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/25071103"}
```

In order to allow CURL to follow the redirect you need to pass the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option while calling soundcloud's get() function.

```
$result = $scloud->get('resolve', array('url' => 'https://soundcloud.com/webfordreams'), array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE ));
```

I'm not too sure about the syntax though but what you eventually wanna end up with is something like this in Soundcloud's _request() function:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Hopefully someone with more experience on this will come along and give you the proper syntax instead of you having to tinker around with the SoundCloud SDK itself.

Answer (score 1):

Leading on from what Francis.G was saying The syntax you are looking for is:

```
$soundcloud->get('resolve', array('url' => 'https://soundcloud.com/webfordreams'), array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true);
```

The only change is in the definition of the curl-ops array passed into the `get()` function as the third parameter.